# How to remove folder/folder name from url using htaccess (2 folder)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

i am working on localhost is it possible or not?

**My Target work is:**

http://localhost/webport/portal/subportal/controlname

**To**
http://localhost/webport/controlname

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /MotoMate/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MotoMate/index.php/$1 [L] 
#AuthType Basic 
#require valid-user 
#Allow valid-user 
#Deny from all 
#Allow from env=test_uri 
#Allow from env=live_url 
#Satisfy any Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^corporate/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R] 
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: it is controller name of my Website.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /MotoMate/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MotoMate/index.php/$1 [L]

#AuthType Basic
#require valid-user
#Allow valid-user
#Deny from all
#Allow from env=test_uri
#Allow from env=live_url
#Satisfy any
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^corporate/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

Comment: hello Pathik Vejani, it's not working , i am working with codeigniter (MVC). on localhost is it possible or not

Comment: My full url:- http://localhost/MotoMate/corporate/company/testing    and my aim url should be http://localhost/MotoMate/testing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^portal/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^subportal/(.*)$ /$0 [L,NC,R]
```